# Which game engine is ideal for a 3D RPG?

Tags: rpg

I am thinking about making a small RPG. I know some basics of openGL, but I do not want create my own engine.

My criteria are:

1. Ease of use
2. Can do rpg
   game
3. 3D

Which game engine is ideal for a 3D RPG?

Comment: What language are you using? And by the sounds of what you want, Unity3D is by far the best option, however subjective that is.

Comment: dont quack red duck, i will wait for some other opinion

Comment: No, I am just stating that Unity3D is almost certainly the best option. And you are not going to get any other options unless you have a language choice.

Comment: You cant answer this "subject question" with a clear answer. you should look on other things such as, what skills does the developer team persist? which platforms do you want to publish this game on? I like Unity3D myself, but others prefere Unreal Engine because of its speed and effects etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it is absolutely Unity3D, and the basic version is for free.

http://unity3d.com/

Good luck

Comment: Ok I will check it, But I will wait a litlebit for othe opinion

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the language you want to use.  [Py-Game or Blender's game engine](http://www.blender.org/education-help/tutorials/game-engine/) are easy to use, in python (so easy) and open source.  If you're going to make a game that requires a *real* engine though, PeterK is completely correct in saying that unity is by far the best (publicly available) engine on the market.

Comment: Pygame has nothing for 3D, but it looks like you really just mean BGE, and not Pygame.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Ploobs Engine, it supports XNA 4, opensource and has lots of features:

www.ploobs.com.br

Answer (score -1):

UDK ia excellent for most jobs, i have yet to find something it cannot do.