# Is there an FBX file/model viewer for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, fbx

Is there a free tool I can use to view and inspect FBX assets? I've got a bunch of FBX files and I'd like to look at the mesh and textures and preview the animations.

Comment: Which technology to use questions are off topic for the site. See the [FAQ] about discussion oriented sites that would be better to ask at.

Comment: @Byte56 Consider this question falling under the allowed "asset pipelines" category.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still "which to use". It doesn't matter what the technology is. It could be [engines](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8440/), [programming languages](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28193/), [math libraries](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9924) or any other gorrila vs shark situation. It's a perfectly valid question, it's just not on topic for this site.

Comment: The question isn't about "which to use", but "does it exist". Seems valid to me.

Comment: "Does it exist" is still a list generating question. I can't imagine someone simply being satisfied with "yes, they exist", without someone also suggesting one. The end result is someone is suggesting which one to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! The FBX Converter can be downloaded from the [FBX Plug-Ins, Converter, and QuickTime Viewer Downloads page](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=10775855). One opened there's an "Add FBX Viewer" button which can display FBX contents and animations.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?id=10775855&siteID=123112

Down the page is a thing called

FBX 2013.3 Plug-in for QuickTime

I think this will allow you to open FBX files in Quicktime.

Comment: I've installed it, but if I try to open one with QuickTime Player I get: "The document “starterUnit.fbx” could not be opened. QuickTime Player cannot open files of this type."

Comment: Also FBX Reviewer is not available for Russia region and there seems to be no other way to download it rather than from stinky AppStore